# Select multiple options from jsp dropdown

Tags: html, jsp, drop-down-menu, options-menu

I have the following code and I want to be able to select multiple options when with a shift button. The following code displays a list of items in a drop down option menu:
I have a table in the DB that have  alist of books, so Iam populating the drop down menu with the table's data.

```
<select name="getfromall" id="getfromall" style="width:16em onChange=getBooks();">

<option value="All"><%=msg.getString("All Books")%></option>
<%
   java.util.ArrayList allBooks = Library.AddBook.getBookList("%");
       for(int i=0;i<allBooksl.size();i++)
              {
          %>
            <option value="<%=((String[])allBooks.get(i))[0]%>"
                      <%
        if( (getfromall1).equals(((String[])allBooks.get(i))[0]) )
                               out.print("selected");%>>

 <%=((String[])allBooks.get(i))[1]%>
</options>
<%
}//end if
%>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `multiple` attribute on your `<select>` tag:

```
<select multiple name="getfromall" ... >
```

Comment: I noticed that the dropdown menu disapeared, I wonder how can I keep the dropdown menu and be able to select two or more items for the list with mouse or shift?

Comment: Selecting multiple options from a dropdown menu is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Use `multiple` to allow multiple selection and `size` to say how many options to be presented to the user.

```
<select name="getfromall" multiple="multiple" size="5" ...>
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/select.html